# Unity2d vs. Corona

Tags: unity-game-engine, coronasdk

I'm using Corona SDK for few months. I really like it but yesterday I discovered Unity2d. It seems to be really expanded.
I'm only interested about 2d games on Android (Google play store) and IOS (AppStore)

Is Unity2d cross platform like Corona SDK? I write there code only once in Lua and I can deploy it on Android or IOS.

Is Unity2d has many plungin like Facebook, twitter, in app pucharse etc. ?

I saw unity Pro but it cost about 80$ per month. Free version is enough to make 2d game and publish it in the future?

What is better corona sdk or unity2d in your opinion to make 2d games for Android or IOS?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unity2D there are many graphical tools and games get faster. Also a better community.

[Tutorial project](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike)

Answer (score 2):

If you already worked a while with corona I would recommend you to stick with it especially if you want to port your game to android.

I did a few cross platform games with unity and had quite some issues with the android port. For 3d games I would recommend unity at any time, but 2D is much simpler and there are many more specialized engines out there. I think Unity is a bit of an overkill for 2D projects.  It does whatever make sense if you plan on developing any 3D game soon because then you have the learning effort once.

Do not get me wrong, Unity is a nice engine, but I do want people to keep in mind that there are other possibly better options for your case out there.

Answer (score 1):

Unity allows for cross platform development yes, and I believe it has plugins for the likes of Facebook and such. As for which is better, SO isn't the right place to ask that.

Comment: they aren't really asking which is better though. They are asking is Unity as good as Corona for the 2d use case for ios + android.

Answer (score 1):

In case of you are asking an opinion which is better, I prefer Unity for a couple of reason. Unity gives huge amount of cross platform option with little effort. Even if you aim mobile platform, you could easily come with pc or console version of a game. Corona is also a cross platform but I think Unity offer better deal.

Do not stuck with Unity Pro. You don't actually need a Pro license to publish a good game. Lots of game in the market are build with Unity Free. Even with Unity 5, lots of pro options are available to the users.

Unity has many plugin in asset store. [Check](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/) if you can find any related topic to your interest.

And in my opinion, the biggest advantage of Unity is its community. A lot of people are using Unity to develop their games and there are tons of tutorials on the internet. As a starter, it's almost impossible not to find a solution when you face with issues.